# mapping already exists for ^I in vim

Tags: vim, code-snippets, keymapping

I have added the following lines to the vimrc file so that i could use s-tab for indenting

```
map <esc>[Z <s-tab>
ounmap <esc>[Z
```

After i have added this , i get the following error. I use SnippetsEmu plugin

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>15_SnipMapKeys:
line   10:
E227: mapping already exists for ^I
```

How do i solve this conflict.Why does this happen

Comment: `^I` is a Tab. But this message should appear if you have mapped `<Tab>` to something, not if you mapped something to `<Tab>`, check the outputs of `verbose map <Tab>`. And are you sure, that vim can distinguish between `<Tab>` and `<S-Tab>`? In most terminals it can't.

Comment: @Zyx :Yeah,it is difficult to distinguish between `<Tab>` and `<S-Tab>` .I was trying a fix on [Make Shift Tab Work](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_Shift-Tab_work) . Well , my problem was what `^I` was , and since i removed the command `map <Tab> >>` from my vimrc , the error stopped showing . Mapping something To tab was the problem then wasn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A helpful way you can detect whether your version of vim is capable of differentiating between Tab and Shift-Tab is to:

Go into insert mode, press <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd>* then <kbd>Shift-Tab</kbd>. I get `<S-Tab>` when I do that (gvim 7.2 on Windows XP).

If you don't get that then I don't think you can map Shift-Tab separately from Tab with your current setup.

*<kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd> will take the next key combination you press and output the key combination that vim actually sees.

EDIT: If you're sourced mswin.vim then you'll want to use <kbd>Ctrl-q</kbd> instead.